# Facebook reply to message

Tags: facebook

I face an issue with replying (from with in an app) to facebook messages received in an application. The facebook is connected via oauth to this app and the FB messages will be delivered into this app.
Jijo AMT (jijo@facebook.com)sent a FB message TO Anjaly AMT(anj@facebook.com).
The Anjaly AMT facebook account is configured in the app and hence the message is delivered in app. Anjaly want to reply for this message to Jijo. Using an email client in app she does it from an email a@amt.in. Although user Jijo gets this message in facebook, it cant be recognized as reply and falls in facebook as a new message.

I would like to know, how the reply can be recognized as a reply to the FB message.( can we take use of any header info, message id etc)

Comment: When the user Anjaly replies to the Facebook message using `a@amt.in`... Is that the email address Anjaly uses to log into Facebook?

Comment: If that is the case, and it still doesn't behave as you excpect, then Facebook doesn't try to make the connection between an incomming message's email address and a user on the site. It will always come in a new message and not as a reply... To be recognized as a reply, Facebook would have to know that it's coming from the same user that sent the original, but because the original was an internal message it's unlikely that it would get combined with a message received from outside the network...